# Using the ArrayList<Object> feature to store Array from Method

Tags: java, arraylist

I am about 95% done I believe, the only thing that is stopping me is that I have to print the results from printInfo() into an element.

The program is gathering input, and the input is based on whether or not the item is a plant. After the input is entered and the setters are ran, I am suppose to access the
printInfo() from plant for example, and store it as an element in the myGarden array.

Then I will call a method that prints the elements of the object array. Those elements will be the information from printInfo() from the plant, and the flower class.

update: I removed casting and simply changed  to , Modified the method as well. Remove the print command since it won't work for what we are trying to do and instead assign myGarden.get(i) to call upon the elements.

```
    package labpackage;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class PlantArrayListExample  {

   // TODO: Define a printArrayList method that prints an ArrayList of plant (or flower) objects 

    public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Plant> myGarden) {
        
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myGarden.size(); ++i) {
               myGarden.get(i).printInfo();
            }
    
    
        }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input;
      
      
      
      
      // TODO: Declare an ArrayList called myGarden that can hold object of type plant
      
      ArrayList<Object> myGarden = new ArrayList<>();
      
   // TODO: Declare variables - plantName, plantCost, colorOfFlowers, isAnnual
      
      String plantName;
      String plantCost;
      String colorOffFlowers;
      boolean isAnnual;
      
      
      
      input = scnr.next();
      while(!input.equals("-1")){
         // TODO: Check if input is a plant or flower
          
          if (input.contains("plant")) { 
              
              Plant plant = new Plant();
          
              plantName = scnr.next();
              
              plantCost = scnr.next();
             
              plant.setPlantName(plantName);
              plant.setPlantCost(plantCost);
              System.out.println();
              
              myGarden.add(plant);
              
          // missing code to add print result as an element                 
        
          }
          
          if (!input.contains("plant")) { 
              
              Flower flower = new Flower();
              
              plantName = scnr.next();
              plantCost = scnr.next();
              isAnnual = scnr.nextBoolean();
              colorOffFlowers = scnr.next();
              
              
              
              
              flower.setPlantName(plantName);
              flower.setPlantCost(plantCost);
              flower.setPlantType(isAnnual);
              flower.setColorOfFlowers(colorOffFlowers);
              System.out.println();

              // missing code to add print result as an element 
              myGarden.add(flower);
          }
          
        
      
         input = scnr.next();
      }
      
      // TODO: Call the method printArrayList to print myGarden
      
      printArrayList(myGarden);
      
   }



}



package labpackage;

public class Plant {
       protected String plantName;
       protected String plantCost;

       public void setPlantName(String userPlantName) {
          plantName = userPlantName;
       }

       public String getPlantName() {
          return plantName;
       }

       public void setPlantCost(String userPlantCost) {
          plantCost = userPlantCost;
       }

       public String getPlantCost() {
          return plantCost;
       }

       public void printInfo() {
          System.out.println("Plant Information: ");
          System.out.println("   Plant name: " + plantName);
          System.out.println("   Cost: " + plantCost);
       }
    }

package labpackage;

public class Flower extends Plant {

       private boolean isAnnual;
       private String colorOfFlowers;

       public void setPlantType(boolean userIsAnnual) {
          isAnnual = userIsAnnual;
       }

       public boolean getPlantType(){
          return isAnnual;
       }

       public void setColorOfFlowers(String userColorOfFlowers) {
          colorOfFlowers = userColorOfFlowers;
       }

       public String getColorOfFlowers(){
          return colorOfFlowers;
       }
       
       @Override
       public void printInfo(){
          System.out.println("Plant Information: ");
          System.out.println("   Plant name: " + plantName);
          System.out.println("   Cost: " + plantCost);
          System.out.println("   Annual: " + isAnnual);
          System.out.println("   Color of flowers: " + colorOfFlowers);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jake, don't forget to add the tag for the language / runtime when you're posting. This seems to be an assignment; what I'm missing is a question: where are you stuck (this is partially explained) and *why*?

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Always include a clear problem description. This place is NOT a free tutor service where people review your code to figure that could be wrong or could be improved.

Comment: Please distill this into a question.  What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the plant or flower info update printArrayList method. You cannot pass a method that returns void to "System.out.println" as a parameter, you must call the method directly because it returns void.

```
public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Plant> objList) {
    for (i = 0; i < objList.size(); ++i) {
       objList.get(i).printInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the resolution in the original post by considering the data you provided me. I kept the array using <Object> then I casted  Plant Class while printing and calling the method from the array list. 

for (int i = 0; i < myGarden.size(); ++i) {
        ((Plant) myGarden.get(i)).printInfo();
        System.out.println();

Comment: it is not recommended to use Object then cast it.

Comment: when trying it this way it created error in eclipse. It says the method printinfo() is undefined.

Comment: because your ptintInfo return void and System.out.println take String parameter. So call just objList.get(i).printInfo() and not System.out.println(objList.get(i).printInfo())

Comment: I just edited the code. Now it works!  I simply just removed Object as the array type and changed it to the Plant class then  myGarden.get(i).printInfo();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Object` as type of elements in your collection (which is most generic), you have to narrow down range of possible types. Since you have good hierarchy here you can use base class. Replace

```
ArrayList <Object> myGarden = new ArrayList();
```

with

```
List<Plant> myGarden = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you will be able to call `printInfo()` method, because all objects in collection will definitely be at least `Plant` or any subclass of that class which means they all will have `printInfo()` method.

```
public static void printArrayList(Collection<Plant> plants) {
    for (Plant p : plants) {
        p.printInfo();  
    }
}
```

Or shorter using Java Stream API

```
myGarden.stream().forEach(Plant::printInfo);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am sure this is going to work but the exercise we are doing requires ArrayList to be used instead of list. Do you have an alternate method or what do I need to adjust in the plantArrayInformation class?  Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I added the fix in my edit.

Comment: @Jake, `ArrayList` is just one of implementations of `List`. My code still uses `ArrayList` as you do in your example (check right-hand-side operator in first and second snippets), so you're fine.

Comment: I learned your method too thankfully. I am just a beginner java programmer and I feel so grateful for someone like you to assist me! The lab for some reason had us set with the arraylist utility, I performed it both ways. So if you tried completing the lab with anything else it wouldn't let you. The funny thing is  I completed it by just calling the method with each of the iterations. I just wanted to complete it by calling the method. I can't thank you enough!